# Convert tuple to a List of first item

Tags: scala

Say I have a method that returns this.

```
Vector[ (PkgLine, Tree) ]()
```

I want to convert this to a List of PkgLines.  I want to drop the Tree off.  I'm not seeing anything in the scala library that would allow me to do this.  Anybody have any simple ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
val list = vector.map(_._1).toList
```

If you have a Tupel `t`, you can access its first element using `t._1`. So with the `map` operation, you're effectively throwing away the trees, and store the `PkgLines` directly. Then you simply convert the `Vector` to `List`.

Comment: `breakOut` is a nice way to skip intermediary `Vector`: `vector.map(_._1)(collection.breakOut): List[PkgLine]`

Answer (score 4):

Using `map` with a selector of the first element of the pair works:

```
scala> val v = Vector[(Int,String)]((5,"5"), (42,"forty-two"))
v: ... = Vector((5,5), (42,forty-two))

scala> v.map(_._1).toList
resN: List[Int] = List(5, 42)
```

Alternatively, you can use `unzip`:

```
scala> val (ints,strings) = v.unzip
ints: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(5, 42)
strings: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String] = Vector(5, forty-two)

scala> ints.toList
resN: List[Int] = List(5, 42)
```